# C++: Return Overloaded [] With "this"

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, return, this

I've overloaded the [] (square brackets) operator of a simple class in C++ to return an integer from an array. I now what to reuse this overloaded operator in a member function. I am having trouble implementing this, as using `*this[ i ]` apparently does not work, although I can reference the operator directly:

```
int & A::operator [] (size_t i)
{

    return ints[ i ];

}
...
int A::getVal ( size_t i) const
{

  // Does not work
  return *this[ i ];

  // Does work
  // return operator []( i );

}
```

Why is it that dereferencing the pointer `this` and using the operator [] results in a compile error but calling the operator directly works?

I get the following error compiling:

> cannot convert from 'const Array' to 'char'

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Take a look at the bane of every programmer's existence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is it that dereferencing the pointer this and using the operator
>   [] results in a compile error

It doesn't. But you have to spell it right. Change

```
return *this[ i ];
```

to

```
return (*this)[ i ];
```

As originally written, it applies `[i]` to `this`, then dereferences the result.

Comment: To explain: This is because the indexing operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`, so when the compiler parses that expression and is deciding which operator to apply first, the `[]` operator wins and the `*` operator is applied to the resultant indexing expression.